# How do I make chainmail in Minecraft legitimately?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hey I have recently started playing Minecraft and found some chainmail but I can't find anything to make chainmail armour with? What resources do I need to make chainmail ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chain mail cannot be crafted, but it can be obtained from villager trading. You'll need to find a blacksmith villager who has the trade for it.

Despite being relatively weak, the trade is rarer than iron or diamond armour.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to trading for it, chain mail is a rare drop worn by zombies and skeletons, but usually very damaged. You can eventually save enough parts from a mob grinder to craft into a full set.

Comment: Also, chain mail can be repaired on an anvil using iron ingots.

Answer (score 7):

There are three ways chainmail armor may be obtained in Minecraft (through gameplay mechanisms as opposed to commands, world editing, etc.):

1. Attacking and killing a skeleton or zombie may yield damaged chainmail armor as a [rare drop](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drops#Rare_drops). This damaged armor can be repaired by crafting or an anvil to produce full-durability chainmail armor. (Note that rare drops cannot be obtained from any unattended grinder; the monster must have been hit by the action of a player, just as is required for obtaining XP.)
2. A blacksmith [villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager) may offer to [trade](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) chainmail armor for emeralds.
3. Chainmail armor may be crafted; however, the crafting material required is [*fire*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire), which cannot be “legitimately” acquired even in creative mode, but only by way of the `/give` command or other world-editing tools.

Once you *have* chainmail armor, it may be repaired like other types of armor; the material for repairing chainmail in an anvil is [*iron ingots*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ingot) (the same material as for repairing iron armor).

Comment: (Yes, this answer doesn't exactly say anything the old answers don't, but I felt there should be a *comprehensive* answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Chain mail can only be made using fire which can only be found in creative mode. You can't make the armor legitimately but you can find it with blacksmith villagers.

However you can also find it with priest villagers. This requires Iron bars with 2 or 3 emeralds. To get an enchanted version or the chain mail.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be found by trading in villages unless dropped by mobs which is rare.